# Difference in assignment between values and pointers?

Tags: c++

I am seeing huge performance difference in tight loops when I do the following:

```
MyObject foo = bar.GetObject();
```

vs

```
MyObject* foo = bar.GetObjectPtr();
```

Where the specifics of the class functions are:

```
class MyClass
{
  MyObject someobject;
  MyObject& GetObject() { return someobject; }
  MyObject* GetObjectPtr() { return &someobject; }
} bar;
```

The assignment in the first line is considerably slower than the second.  Can someone explain what is going on?  Does this have something to do with the default copy assignment?

Comment: These two lines should do pretty much the same thing. Are you sure this isn't an artifact of something else in your code.

Comment: What's a "huge" performance difference, and how are you testing it?

Comment: Are you really doing `MyObject &foo = bar.GetObject();` or are you actually doing `MyObject &foo = ...; foo = bar.GetObject();`?

Comment: Oh geez.  I made a typo in the above.  I meant "MyObject foo = ...".

Comment: There's a huge difference between `MyObject foo = ...;` and `MyObject *foo = &...;` One of those sets a pointer and one makes a copy which can involve an arbitrarily large amount of work, including very slow operations like allocating memory...

Comment: Thanks bames53!  Yes, that was exactly the problem.  I wish my eyes would have seen that earlier on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you posted is really the code you tested, then there must be something wrong with your testing methodology, since virtually any modern compiler will generate the same code for both variants (resulting in no performance difference of any kind, of course).

If you are testing something else, then you have to provide more details about your test.

Comment: The code I posted is a simplification of my project.  Obviously in reality the class contains more member functions.  The problem I noticed is described exactly as I mentioned -- that returning a reference was slower than a pointer.  I ran each line in tight loops to verify that.

Comment: @dracore: You mean that you noticed the difference on a "heavier" loop and then narrowed the source to the above? Sorry, I just don't believe it. Even if some compiler decided to generate slightly different code for the two variants above, it won't really be noticeable in a "heavier" loop. Anyway, can you post the assembly that your compiler generates for your tight loop?

Comment: My project needs to call the above mentioned function a number of times and that's when I noticed that I perceived a noticeable loss in performance when using the 1st line.  I am just trying to understand what can cause such a difference as I am scratching my head.  I thought it might have something to do with the default copy assignment.... but honestly, I have no clue.

Comment: @dracore: A typical mistake people make in such cases is they do `MyObject foo = bar.GetObject()` instead of `MyObject& foo = bar.GetObject()`, i.e. forget the `&` symbol on the receiving side. This will, of course, have a considerable performance impact, since it actually receives the object by value (i.e. *copies* the result by copy constructor).

Comment: Thanks AndreyT!  That solved it!  It was a mistake on my end.. did not catch that.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically,

1. Pointers and references are *identical* in resulting machine code,
   except the compiler can do better optimizations in some cases with
   references thanks to less aliasing fun.
2. You almost certainly have no profiling data whatsoever that indicates that this line is a problem. In fact, that variable probably doesn't even *exist* in the resulting machine code and is directly accessed. This means that attempting to determine its performance is a giant waste of time for all involved.
3. Your micro benchmark code is thoroughly flawed in execution. Even a non-optimizing compiler would produce equal results for these two lines. If you had posted the benchmark code, I could be more specific.

The *real* problem in the code posted is the massive encapsulation violation presented.

Comment: Turns out there was a typo in the question such that the use of a reference is not at all like using a pointer in this case. The actual code is apparently comparing pointer assignment with a copy constructor.